# socket.on('connection' ... event never fired nodejs + express + socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, express, socket.io

**Problem** socket.io NOT working

**Details**

- Generated a project with `express [folder]; cd [folder]; npm install;`
- Setup socket.io `npm install socket.io`
- Run node app with below code
- Client **connect** event fires but server **connection** NEVER fired.

**Setup**

- ***Server*** AWS Free Tier, Ubuntu 11.10, ami-a7f539ce
- nodejs v0.6.5
- express v2.5.1
- socket.io v0.8.7

**Client**

```
 var socket = io.connect('http://example.com:3000');

 socket.on('connect', function() { 
    console.log('connected');
 });

 socket.on('message', function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
 });

 socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('disconnected');
 });

 socket.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('System', e ? e : 'A unknown error occurred');
 });
```

**Server**

```
 [...]

 app.listen(3000);

 // socket.io setup
 var socket = require('socket.io').listen(app);

 // socket.io connection establishment
 socket.on('connection', function (client) {
    client.send("hello");
    console.log("hello", client);           
 });
```

Why is **connection** event never fired?

Comment: `io.connect('http://example.com:3000')` -> `io.connect('http://localhost:3000')` ?

Comment: example.com was on purpose, not to expose my servers here. Sorry didn't clarified that.

Comment: Are you sure the rest of the code is working? Do you see _any_ messages?

Comment: @Tadeck it's really weird, look socket.io debug out it's seems to be working ok, doesn't it? but ***connection*** event never gets fired.
[SSH-terminal screen](http://i39.tinypic.com/jkzlhw.png)

Comment: I tested your exact code and it worked. What do you get on the browser's console?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Took a while to notice... the `connection` event is emmited on `io.sockets`. In your code this would be

```
socket.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
  client.send("hello")
  console.log("hello", client)
})
```

You should use `io` instead of `socket` as the var name to avoid this confusion.

Comment: example.com was on purpose, not to expose my servers here. Sorry didn't clarified that.

Comment: i have same problem. but windows machine is working socketio.listen(server).on('connection', function (socket) { }); but mac os isnt worked.

Answer (score 1):

[Ricardo Tomasi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/467019/ricardo-tomasi) is correct, saved my life, i was going crazy.

Altough things changed, we are in 2013, [there's still an issue opened (since 2 years) on this](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/255)

probably something changed, anyway to register the 'connect' event i had to do this:

```
var openSocket = function (uniqueID) {
  var appSocket = io.connect('/'+uniqueID, { transports: ['websocket', 'xhr-polling']});
  appSocket.socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('i did connect.');
  });
  return appSocket;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The following did a trick for me with: socket.io-client: "^0.9.16"

```
io.connect("http://localhost:4000", {'force new connection': true});
```

Now 'connect' event fires consistently and there is no re-use.

I figured out this option by examining socket.io-client/lib/io.js line: 192
Since I can't even find this io.js file in github, I think there is refactoring in future releases, and this option might not work.

At least this might be helpful to somebody who will take this temporary work around.