# Websocket with socket.io and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to use socket.io with express, i used the **express generator**. I cannot view any log from console.

> Before write this i Followed the most voted solution from Gabriel
>   Hautclocq on
>   [Using socket.io in Express 4 and express-generator's /bin/www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609991/using-socket-io-in-express-4-and-express-generators-bin-www)

My code:

***app.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');
var app = express();
var io = socket();
app.io = io;
// var for routes
var index = require('./routes/index')(io);
// Routes
app.use('/', index);

module.exports = app;
```

***bin/www***

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = app.io;
io.attach(server);
```

***routes/index.js***

```
var passport = require('passport');
/* GET home page. */
module.exports = function(io){
  var app = require('express');
  var router = app.Router();
  var controller = require('../controllers/indexController');
  router.get('/', controller.plain);
  /*socket*/
  io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('conectado desde index.js');
    console.log('conectado desde index.js');
    console.log('conectado desde index.js');
  });
  return router;
}
```

***controllers/indexController.js***

> ***Edit with full content from indexController.js***

```
var Account = require('../models/accounts');
var Fav = require('../models/favs');
var Project = require('../models/projects');
var Message = require('../models/messages');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = {
    plain : function (req, res) {
      Project.find(function(err, projects){
        Account.find(function(err, userOwner){
          if(req.user)
            Fav.find({'favUserId': req.user.id},function(err, favs){
              res.render('index',{
                title: "myAplication",
                user: req.user,
                listProjects : projects,
                listUsers : userOwner,
                listFavs : favs
              });
            });
          else
            res.render('index',{
              title: "myAplication",
              listProjects : projects,
              listUsers : userOwner,
            });
        });
      });

    },
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [socket.on('connection' ... event never fired nodejs + express + socket.io](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424886/socket-onconnection-event-never-fired-nodejs-express-socket-io)

Comment: not is the same, review the code in the link, i tried some solutions and also don't works.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the event to `io.on('connect', ...`?

Comment: yes, and nothing happens.

Comment: How do you start your app? `node app.js`?

Comment: i move to the bin folder and make nodemon www

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
//in app.js
app.set('socketio', io);

//in any route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const io = req.app.get('socketio');
})
```