# why firefox does not emit after connection (client side)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

My game works with other browsers but with Firefox, there is a one small but major issue. Why firefox does not emit the "new-player" message after socket connection,  other browsers work OK , all browsers output HELLO to console...and register themself.

```
const newPlayer = (socket, player) => {
  socket.on('connect', () => {

  console.log("HELLO this row appears in all browsers"); 
    socket.emit('new-player', { 
      x: player.sprite.body.x,
      y: player.sprite.body.y,
      angle: player.sprite.rotation,
      playerName: {
        name: String(socket.id),
        x: player.playerName.x,
        y: player.playerName.y
      },
      speed: {
        value: player.speed,
        x: player.speed.x,
        y: player.speed.y
      }
    })
  })
}

export default newPlayer
```

problem on server side: new-player message not received with firefox, other browsers ok:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {   // When a player connects   
    socket.on('new-player', state => {
    console.log(socket.id+'New player joined with state:', state)
    players[socket.id] = state  //stones[socket.id] = state
    // Emit the update-players method in the client side
    io.emit('update-players', players)  //io.emit('update-stones', stones)   })

  //   note the following invalid move command  occurs  on firefox see logs
 socket.on('move-player', data => {
    // If the player is invalid, return
    if (players[socket.id] === undefined) {
        console.log(socket.id+' invalid move')
      return
    }
```

server output with firefox:

```
> [nodemon] 1.14.10 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
> [nodemon] watching: *.* [nodemon] starting `babel-node
> server/index.js` Game server running on: 8000 O14Q_E5LXJi3oYmGAAAA
> invalid move O14Q_E5LXJi3oYmGAAAA invalid move O14Q_E5LXJi3oYmGAAAA
> invalid move O14Q_E5LXJi3oYmGAAAA invalid move O14Q_E5LXJi3oYmGAAAA
> invalid move
```

server output with CHROME browser  OR  if the server is restarted (while firefox stays open , game on screen )

```
> nodemon server/index.js --exec babel-node

[nodemon] 1.14.10
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `babel-node server/index.js`
Game server running on: 8000
55e5xgecEJ-QX_MqAAAANew player joined with state: { x: 2164.6852111816406,
  y: 298.809814453125,
  angle: 0,
  playerName:
   { name: '55e5xgecEJ-QX_MqAAAA',
     x: 2162.938232421875,
     y: 298.80773544311523 },
  speed: { value: 105 } }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [socket.on('connection' ... event never fired nodejs + express + socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424886/socket-onconnection-event-never-fired-nodejs-express-socket-io)

Comment: @ThomasKleßen Definitely not a duplicate, the question you linked was a server-side error, therefore would be an issue that would affect every browser.

Comment: This is clientside issue. One idea just got, should I try to add some sleep() there before sending socket.emit,  could it make a difference...?

Comment: Are you serving any content over https ? If you mix an insecure websocket protocol (ws) with https firefox 8 +  will explicitly not allow this.

Comment: So you don't get the console `Hello` at all in firefox? Are you able to see in the network tab that the websocket is connected?

Comment: socket works, emit not

Comment: please see the updated question , there are server logs now

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is actually having two browsers connected at the same time, if you already have chrome open when you test firefox? Also what is outputting "invalid move"?

Comment: Also check the browser compatibility table here for potential issues with using arrow functions in firefox (depending on which version you have and whether or not you're using "use strict") https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility

Comment: invalid move command  occurs  on firefox 
 socket.on('move-player', data => {
    // If the player is invalid, return
    if (players[socket.id] === undefined) {
        console.log(socket.id+' invalid move')
      return
    }

Comment: No, problem does not occur with 2 browsers, just firefox,  there can be even n+1 browsers in game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems this makes it work

```
const newPlayer = (socket, player) => {
  socket.on('connect', () => {

  console.log("do nothing here actually, just log "+socket);
})

    socket.emit('new-player', { 
      x: player.sprite.body.x,
      y: player.sprite.body.y,
      angle: player.sprite.rotation,
      playerName: {
        name: String(socket.id),
        x: player.playerName.x,
        y: player.playerName.y
      },
      speed: {
        value: player.speed,
        x: player.speed.x,
        y: player.speed.y
      }
    })

}

export default newPlayer
```